# Is there a key-less synth/midi controller to control and modulate my Yamaha keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, midi, synthesizer, midi-controller-keyboard, modulation

Newbie here. I already own a Yamaha keyboard, which is pretty much like a piano but with all the options for DJ and change of tone etc. I want to be able to modulate pitch and such with modulation wheels and knobs and sliders. All of which I know are available on midi controllers but I want one without the keyboard; Since I already have one (a keyboard). So basically, is there any way to synth my existing keyboard... like a keyboard-less MIDI controller... that I can connect to my Yamaha?

THANKSS

Comment: A KP3 is has a touch screen with 2 axis control (like having 2 sliders controlled at the same time with 1 finger), are you exclusively looking for something with physical sliders or is touch screen also an option?

Comment: Go to a large music store, explain to the salesperson what it is you want to do, and they will show you equipment that they sell that will do it, and explain and demonstrate its use. This will save you a lot of time over doing a lot of searching online when you don't know enough to ask the right questions.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of MIDI controllers that are just buttons, sliders, and knobs.  [See here](http://www.sweetwater.com/c513--MIDI_Controllers?params=eyJmYWNldCI6eyJUeXBlIjpbIlBhZCJdfX0) for a pretty wide selection.

The usual way to connect these if you're looking to augment an existing keyboard is to plug the new controller into the keyboard's MIDI IN, so that from the computer's perspective it looks like everything is coming from the keyboard.

Comment: thanks for your help - so could I adjust say, the pitch of a note from my Keyboard, using one of these controllers? (As modulation wheels would do)